# When will microsoft push Silverlight as part of Windows OS or through windows update?

Tags: windows, silverlight

What is your educated guess? Have you seen/heard any news/interview/quotes from any Microsoft employees?

Comment: AFAIK, it does push silverlight via Windows Updates.Just that it is in the optional updates section.

Comment: As if my windows install/updates aren't bloated enough...

Comment: Isn't Silverlight basically dead now (except for on WP7?).

Comment: @Sean - MS walked back Muglia's misstatement pretty significantly. On top of the fact that Muglia never said anything like "Silverlight is dead," MS has announced details of SL5, they've had all sorts of vice presidents running around talking up Silverlight, and the SL evangelists have been working overtime to make sure people know that Silverlight will still be around and still be promoted.

Comment: @Ken Smith Thanks for clarifying (I deleted my long rant re:the usefulness of SL since it's OT, but don't use SL, Flash or Flex any more, m'kay).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, Microsoft does push Silverlight via Windows Updates. Refer to this [example KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982926).

> An update (version 4.0.50524.0) is
>   available for Microsoft Silverlight.
>   This update offers a new build that is
>   an upgrade to earlier versions of
>   Silverlight. This update is included
>   in current Silverlight installers. If
>   your computer does not have
>   Silverlight installed, the installer
>   will be offered to you by Microsoft
>   Update or by Windows Server Update
>   Services (WSUS).

Note: Micosoft includes silverlight in optional update category. So most probably corporates and people with low bandwidth may not install it.

Answer (score 0):

When you click through those EULAs for Windows Update, part of the agreement between you and Microsoft is the definition of a "High Priority" update (i.e. ones that get installed automatically). This agreement details that these updates are pushed out only for specific reasons, security being the primary one.  This should give you enough information to infer when Silverlight will get pushed out as a non-optional update.